# Graphical query designer for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, query-builder

I have for years used MS Access and its query tool that is used for making queries. This tool is so good that I have never been forced to do very much SQL programming myself. The query tool has done all the work.

However, now I have started using Postgres and the Graphical Query Builder in pgAdmin. It seems that the Graphical Query Builder is rather primitive: It cannot be used if you need an aggregate function like SUM or COUNT.

Is this really correct?

Does anybody know a better graphical query builder for PostgreSQL?

Until now I have 'solved' the problem by linking MS Access to the Postgres database through ODBC and used MS Access' query tool to generate SQL commands which I then copy into pgAdmin's Graphical Query Builder - and edit the SQL commands until everything is correct.

Comment: I never understood the need for a query builder. They make the easy things possible, the complex things hard and the advanced things impossible.

Comment: if you (like me) is new to SQL programming a good query builder makes the easy things easy, the complex things possible, and the advanced things can perhaps only be made by basic SQL programming. But still: For simple and complex things you can use a good query builder!

Comment: From my experience: you will never learn SQL properly if you stick to a query builder. And you will never understand errors you get when running generated statements if you don't understand how SQL works.

Comment: Apparently not - my guess is because nobody uses a query builder for any serious SQL development.

Comment: A query builder is not a developer tool so you are asking in the wrong site. Try [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: PgAdmin3 has the only graphical query builder for PostgreSQL.
Unlike super professional responders above, who apparently never really construct complex views, I perfectly understood the need but I didnt find anything even close to SQL Server tools.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Maestro has a query designer, although it is PC only, AFAIK

http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/postgresql/maestro/screenshots/getting_started/visual_query_builder/

EMS SQL Manager also has a query designer

http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/postgresql/manager/screenshots

Comment: And for Linux? There are something?

Answer (score 0):

Try SQLeo, its free and has a specific feature (autosavepoint) to prevent

ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block.

Answer (score 0):

Try a browser-based query builder for PostgreSQL called Skyvia. And you don’t have to worry about which operating system it works. It works where a browser exists. Simply make a connection to your PostgreSQL database and start building your queries. See a sample below.

[image]

Note that you can still switch between SQL code and query builder if you want to, just like in MS Access. Get the details [here](https://skyvia.com/query/online-postgresql-query-builder).